# How to implement scroll synchronization functionality in pdf document comparison?

Tags: javascript, angular

Draftable website providing scrolling synchronization functionality while comparing two different version documents.
how to implement same with Angular 4+

please find my code here
[How to synchronize the scroll behavior while comparing two different pdf version documents in Angular 4+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76912930/how-to-synchronize-the-scroll-behavior-while-comparing-two-different-pdf-version)

please check the below URL for example

[Draftable website URL](https://draftable.com/compare/lMnXBMXWqaqy)

**Scroll Synchronization means: if we scroll left / right document same content will show on right/left document (two documents have some differences).**

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76927319/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: please check code here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76912930/how-to-synchronize-the-scroll-behavior-while-comparing-two-different-pdf-version